# Merge WMS Image tile layers in OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I have an app which generates points into a database in every 5 seconds, and I have a GeoServer which generates PNG tiles from these points. The last part of my app is based on OpenLayers v5.3 and displays the tiles from GeoServer on WMS layers.

Since the new tiles means new extent for the WMS tile layer, first time I updated the extent of the layer to display the tiles. Doing this caused a "blinking layer", so the layer refreshed all the tiles every time I updated its extent.

My current solution for this problem is to create new WMS layer for every new chunk of data, but this generates me a lot of them and makes my app laggy and slow after a time. I created some logic to merge layers after 2 minutes by creating one big layer from the summarized extent, but this also causes a refres of the tiles and requests Geoserver unnecessarily.

Is there a way to merge WMS layers without rerequesting the tiles they already loaded? Or can I update its extent without rerquesting all the tiles but only the new ones?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

While you are loading new data from geoserver, your layer is getting unvisible and when your data is loaded your layer is getting visible. This is what i understand from your question. But openlayers image layers does not hide-remove last image from map. I think your code is unsual.